# Whats the Good Practice of Possible Linq Result Data Storage to be used Globally within Solution

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How do i do this the proper way legit code. like if it do a linq query within using and the result is i want it to use on another different bracket of using another call of linq query

if i store it i could declare a pre define var neither can i use a class constructor method.
what is the proper way to do this that i may able to use it on maybe different modules or different function / method without again doing the same call over in every method.

Hope i made it clear what i want.

```
var globalstorage;

using (Si360DbContext _si360DbContext = new Si360DbContext())
            {
                var selectedItems = _si360DbContext.SaleDumpDetails
                .Where(sd => sd.SaleID == saleid)
                .Select(i => i.SaleItemID).ToList();

                //Store data..
                globalstorage = selectedItems;
            }

// able to reuse it else where having the same data stored on it.
globalstorage
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends... as always...
If you're working on a web project, some mechanism that allows you to cache would be approprate. A MemoryCache for example could be a good and fast solution. However... If the amount of data grows, or you run multiple instances of the same website for example, you may need a distributed cache system like Redis.

For different types of apps, console or maybe Windows desktop you could just create a public static variable and you're good to go. So again, it totally depends on the needs of your solution.

Comment: I have a flow of codes where im doing a using(dbContext db = new dbContext) {} and inside that parameter there is a certain that i will again try to open another DB Context of it without closing the 1st call i made which sometimes causes an error with multiple attemp connections when handling lots of datas

Comment: which is why i wanted to do like a using(dbContext) call and then if possible the result of that database connection i can store it to a holder so if i open another using call some of the values on the 1st call i want to use it. it would be easy and also i would not use another query linq by recalling the data collections again

Comment: oh and by the way im using a Console .netcore apps. its like a command line programming interface C#